# Jquery function problem

Tags: jquery, function, hover

I'm having a problem with my code. It works fine when the cursur is over the div, but it doesn'ts stop on mouseout. Any ideas what I've done wrong? (I'm using the jquery-approach plugin)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#wrap p").hover(function () {      
  $("span.fg").approach({"opacity": 1,}, 100);
  $("span.fg").animate({fontSize: '15px'}, 300);
      $("span.bg").animate({fontSize: '8px'}, 300);
    },
     function () {      
       $(this).removeClass("hover");
      }  
   );   
});
```

HTML: (links are a href, I'm a new user)

```
<div id="wrap" class="">
<h2>Stuff</h2>
    <p class="on">
        <span class="bg">Lorem Ipsum has been the</span> 
        <link "#"><span class="fg"> industry’s standard</span></a> 
        <span class="bg">dummy text ever</span> 
        <link ="#"><span class="fg">since the 1500s,</span></a> 
        <span class="bg">when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</span> 
        <link ="#"><span class="fg">scrambled it</span></a> 
        <span class="bg">to make a type specimen book.</span>
        <link ="#"><span class="fg">scrambled it</span></a> 
        <span class="bg">to make a type specimen book.</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your html as well

Comment: what's the expected behavior?

Comment: Basically, when mousing over the div #wrap, words with the 'fg' span will grow and brighten as the mouse gets closer, the 'bg' span will shrink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned class hover, you have called jquery method [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

You need to either refactor and create a class (eg myHover, then add and remove), or set the spans back to their orignal value using the hover method like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#wrap p").hover(
      function () {      
      $("span.fg").approach({"opacity": 1,}, 100);
      $("span.fg").animate({fontSize: '15px'}, 300);
      $("span.bg").animate({fontSize: '8px'}, 300);
    },
     function () {      
        $("span.fg").approach({"opacity": 0,}, 100); //change back to orginal value
        $("span.fg").animate({fontSize: '10x'}, 300); //change back to orginal value
        $("span.bg").animate({fontSize: '4px'}, 300); //change back to orginal value
      }  
   );   
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nim,
I've tried this code, my problem is it doesn't reset completely on mouseout, the opacity stays on and the font sizes continue to fluctuate when outside the div. Could this be the 'approach' plugin causing the problem?

Comment: Could be, didn't notice you were you using that plugin before.

Comment: Hey Nim,
Is there a way to code it so that as you enter the div the hover function begins, and when you leave it simply removes everything associated with the function?